# Read the output of a container in another containerized C# script

Tags: c#, docker

I wrote two example scripts in C#. The first generates random numbers (one per second), and the second reads the output of the first and print "even" or "odd". On my desktop these scripts and the communication works fine, but when I created the two separates container (maybe obviously) the communication didn't work due to the local path that doesn't exist in the container. I suppose that this purpose requires to change the code a little bit but I don't know how.

This is a simple schema of the communication:
[image]

And here I add the complete C# scripts for a reproducible example.

Number Generator script:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace generator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                int number = rnd.Next(0, 100);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Reader script:

```
using System;

namespace reader
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;
    class StandardAsyncOutputExample
    {
        //private static int lineCount = 0;
        private static StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\generator\bin\Debug\net5.0\generator.exe"; 
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                int result = Int32.Parse(e.Data);
                if (result % 2 == 0){
                    Console.WriteLine($"{result} e' un numero pari");
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{result} e' un numero dispari");
                }
            });

            process.Start();

            // Asynchronously read the standard output of the spawned process.
            // This raises OutputDataReceived events for each line of output.
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();

            // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
            Console.WriteLine(output);

            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

If could be helpful I could add more details. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Consider using a messaging system like Kafka or RabbitMQ here: the producer sends things to the message bus, and the consumer receives them from there, without them being directly connected to each other.  That will translate well into Docker but doesn't specifically require it.

Comment: (If your actual problem is really this simple, also consider a plain function call or running the producer as a separate thread within the same process.)

Comment: Thanks David! So if I wanted to keep the scripts (and the two containers) separate, you suggest to use Kafka or RabbitMQ to make them communicate?

Comment: For a setup where one container generates a stream of data that needs to be received by another, those seem like better technology matches.  If the data wasn't so continuous, having the consumer make an HTTP call to the producer to retrieve a batch of data would also be a typical approach.  More generally, things in Docker should use network-oriented communication protocols, and not try to communicate via shared files or pipes.

Comment: Ok, thanks David you were very helpful!